# Método que retorne diferentes tipos de entidades MVC EF6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

estoy tratando hacer un método que me retorne el tipo de objeto según un string que yo le pase por parámetros al db context.

Ejemplo:

```
private MyContext _context = new MyContext();
private TipoEntidadX GetSelectOption(int id, string entidad)
{
    var entidadARetornar = _context.entidad.Find(id);
    return entidadARetornar;
}
```

El problema es que si intento hacer esto **_context.entidad** me dice que el context no contiene una definición para esa propiedad.
alguna idea?

Comment: Y cual seria el problema que estas teniendo? podes aclararlo?

Comment: El problema es que si intento hacer esto _context.entidad me dice que el context no contiene una definición para esa propiedad.

Answer (score 0):

Haz que tu entidad de salida tenga las n cantidad de entidades posibles a retornar como atributos. Con el id identificas cual debes retornar.

Comment: Eso es lo que estoy tratando de evitar pero si no encuentro la forma lo haré

Comment: O lo otro que puedes hacer es retornar un objeto tipo Object y luego afuera parsearlo por el objeto que sabes solicitaste. O mejor aun, retornar un string tipo json y eso parsearlo al objeto que requieres.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tu preguntas es obtener el tipo del objeto. Eso te lo la la función de [.GetType()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is).

Ahora, lo que dice tú código es distinto. El cual intentas obtener el registros desde un contexto, pero esa tabla la preguntas desde el string de la entidad.

Pero el la entidad de tu contexto ya debe de ser previamente definido en la clase de `MyContext();`

```
private MyContext _context = new MyContext();
private TipoEntidadX GetSelectOption(int id)
{
    var lst = _context.TipoEntidadX.toList();
    var obj =lst.FirstOfDefault(w => w.id == id);
    return obj;
}
```

El resultado de un contexto es un dataset de la entidad, por eso es muy recomendable aplicar un **toList();** al contexto. 
Y como buscas retornar un solo tipo de dato puedes filtrar en la misma función de **FirstOfDefault()** que te da el primer elemento de la lista.

Utilizar el string directamente en el contexto es posible, pero aún así es nacesario la clase del tipo de datos para que los retome tipo

```
public TEntity Get<TEntity>(string name)
{
    var enumerable = (IEnumerable<TEntity>)(typeof([ClassNameOfContext]).GetProperty(name).GetValue(ctx, null));
    return enumerable.ToList();
}
```

> Adición: es posible que también se deshaga del parámetro de cadena; se
>   deben evitar nombres de tipos o propiedades en cadenas siempre que sea
>   posible, ya que no es seguro. El compilador no lo reconoce y las
>   funciones IDE, como las refactorizaciones, no lo tienen en cuenta. El
>   problema aquí es que los nombres de propiedad suelen ser la forma
>   pluralizada de los nombres de tipo de entidad. Pero podría usar el
>   reflejo para encontrar la propiedad cuyo tipo coincida con el TEntity.
>   Lo dejo como ejercicio :-)

Comment: Lo que quiero es que _context.TipoEntidadX sea el nombre que paso como string así puedo reutilizar para cualquier entidad

Comment: Agregue esa parte

Comment: Gracias hermano

Comment: marcala como correcta Hector.... es la mejor forma de agradecer.